# SVG curved text along a circle clip path element not displaying

Tags: html, css, svg

Here's a link to my codepen: https://codepen.io/Bryandbronstein/pen/QVaQpa

So basically what I have is an svg circle set as a clipPath element to cut my image into a circle.  Then I want to curve my text around the circle, rather than it being in a straight line on top of my circular image, like this:

[image with curved text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oIbT1.png)

The thing is, I have this image to show off as my example because this code works in Firefox, but no other browser I could test.  What gives?
Here's my code:

```
        <svg height="300" width="350">
        <defs>
            <clipPath id="circleView">
                <circle id="curve" cx="150" cy="180" r="110" fill="transparent" />
            </clipPath>
        </defs> 

        <text x="390" y="-20" width="100">
            <textpath id="homepageText" xlink:href="#curve">
                My Homepage!
            </textpath>
        </text>

        <image width="300" height="410" xlink:href="meee.jpg" clip-path="url(#circleView)" />

    </svg>
```

Just to clarify, I have moderate experience in HTML and CSS but very little in SVG.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `path` insted of `circle`, and `text-anchor` + `startOffset` to center the text:

```
<svg x="0px" y="0px" width="350" height="300" viewBox="0 0 350 300">
  <defs>
    <path id="curve" d="M40,180c0-60.751,49.248-110,110-110c60.751,0,110,49.249,110,110"/>
  </defs>
  <text fill="black" class="curved-text">
    <textPath xlink:href="#curve" text-anchor="middle" startOffset="50%">My homepage!</textPath>
  </text>
</svg>
```

Working [Codepen](https://codepen.io/gazdagergo/pen/qMpwNo?editors=1010).

Comment: I didn't know about text-anchor or startOffset before; very useful.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Using svg path tag we can achieve curved text. Below is the modification to your code. Corrected x and y for text tag and have added path with id "forText.

```
<svg height="300" width="350">
        <defs>
            <clipPath id="circleView">
                <circle id="curve" cx="150" cy="180" r="110" fill="transparent" />
            </clipPath>
        </defs> 
        <path id="forText" d="M32,110, C25,90, 180,-39,290,130" stroke="" fill="none"/>
            <text x="0" y="35" width="100">
                <textpath xlink:href="#forText">
                    My Homepage!
                </textpath>
            </text>
    <image width="300" height="410" xlink:href="meee.jpg" clip-path="url(#circleView)" />
</svg>
```